# Laravel 7: the browser sees the compiled CSS files but doesn't apply them

Tags: css, laravel, browser, laravel-7

**The problem**: the CSS is correctly compiled and linked but doesn't show in page.

I am using Laravel 7.24 in a local project.

The code from `app.scss` seems to be correctly compiling into `public/css/app.css`.

In my view's `<head>`, I linked the stylesheet like so: `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`. In the browsers' elements/inspector tab, it reads as `<link href="http://localhost:8000/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">`. Adding the optional attribute `type="text/css"` changes nothing.

Opening the view in Chrome, visually the page has no css applied to it. Looking at the network tab of the dev tools, app.css is listed with a `net::ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` error.

Opening the same file in Firefox, the browser ignores the first selector it finds and applies everything else. In the dev tools' network tab, app.css is listed without any type of status, but I can access the file and see that all the properties are there. In the following example, both the `h1` and `p` render correctly, but removing the first `.class` selector causes the h1 to render as black text with no strike through. (`.class` does not exist in my view, I just needed something to put as first selector.)

```
.class {
    color: purple;
}

h1 {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

p {
    color: blue;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

I tried clearing my cache, but to no avail.

I can access my css file directly at `http://localhost:8000/css/app.css`, where it shows my properties plus these lines (as far as I can tell, similar lines are also present in projects that do work):

```
‹������
���������HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Host: localhost:8000
Date: Sun, 30 Aug 2020 16:24:08 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 175
```

Any idea on what could be the reason for this behavior?

ETA: **I found the solution**. Using the command `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` instead of `php artisan serve` solved my issue.

Comment: Change the APP_URL environment variable in your .env file to  http://127.0.0.1:8000 then restart your app

Comment: @FKIng I just tried to follow your advice, but the end result remains the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fumbling I remembered I was once told that `php artisan serve` could sometimes cause issues with the CSS, so I looked around for the alternative and used the `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` command instead. That seemed to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

So after you ran `npm run dev` you cannot see your applied css, even though caching is turned off?

Do you work with `php artisan serve` or with xampp?

It seems that `php artisan serve` should only be used for a quick start, and if you wanna really use laravel you should set up a real apache server or something similar.

Comment: I generally start both artisan serve and mamp. And in the meantime I found the solution, which was to use the `php -S localhost:8000 -t public/` command instead of artisan serve.